# Swift String, Character Concatenation Plus Assignment

Tags: string, swift, character, xcode6

I'm getting this with Xcode 6.1(6A1046a), as I did with 6.0:

```
var dog:String = "Dog"
let plural:Character = "s"    
let dogs:String = dog.append(plural)
```

Playground reports:

> Playground execution failed: :29:23: error: cannot invoke
>   'append' with an argument of type 'Character' let dogs:String =
>   dog.append(plural)

Why can I not do this, although this is fine:

```
dog.append(plural)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is misleading, but the problem is that

```
mutating func append(c: Character)
```

modifies its receiver and returns `Void` (aka `()` aka "nothing"):

```
var dog:String = "Dog"
let plural:Character = "s"    
dog.append(plural) // now dog contains the string "Dogs"
```

With

```
let dogs = dog + String(plural)
```

you can create a new string instead.

*Remark:* You could actually assign

```
let foo = dog.append(plural)
```

but that would assign the empty tuple `()` to `foo` (which is not what you intend).
The error message in your code is caused by the fact that you cannot assign `()`
to a `String` variable.